# Debugging Istio-enabled Java application

Tags: openshift, remote-debugging, jdb, istio

I am trying to remote-debug a java application running in Openshift with Istio, therefore as a pod with one docker container with the app itself and another one container with the Envoy proxy.

I have set up the debug arguments on the java process:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

and the process has the port opened, and wrote:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

However, when I try to connect to that both from outside and from the container itself, I get:

```
> jdb -attach 172.17.0.8:5005
java.io.IOException: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.handshake(SocketTransportService.java:136)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.attach(SocketTransportService.java:232)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericAttachingConnector.attach(GenericAttachingConnector.java:116)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketAttachingConnector.attach(SocketAttachingConnector.java:90)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.attachTarget(VMConnection.java:519)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.open(VMConnection.java:328)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Env.init(Env.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.TTY.main(TTY.java:1066)

Fatal error:
Unable to attach to target VM.
```

My suspicion is that this is related to the proxying by Istio which does not understand the JDWP and messes with that (to my surprise even when accessing from withing the container using

```
oc exec -it myservice-42-abcdef -c myservice bash
```

but I can't check iptables from the container as I don't have root there).

Is my suspect correct? How can I disable the proxying on certain ports?

Comment: Looks like you are connecting to the service right? Have you exposed 5505 on the svc?

Comment: I have not exposed the service yet; I didn't need to name it. However the fact that even connection *from within* the container fails tells me that this is affected.

Answer (score 1):

You must define services on the ports you access by your Istio-enabled pods, even for access on the local host. You must name the port `<protocol>[-<suffix>]`, for example `tcp-jdwp`. See the requirements for Istio-enabled pods https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/sidecar-injection.html#pod-spec-requirements .